# how to read sms from 4g router over wired lan

Tags: python, sms, router, lan, 4g

**Objective**:

- I am building an IOT application on raspberry pi that requires me to read SMS (i.e. mobile text messages)

**My set up**:

- I have a 4g router with sim. [router](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/3g-4g-router/tl-mr6400/)
- I have a raspberry pi 4 B connected to the router over RJ45 (Lan) connection.
- I can connect to the admin interface of the router and both send and receive SMS (text messages).

**Question**

- **Is there a way to read SMS using python ?**

  - *I have seen several examples using USB dongles with serial interface and I am tempted to try a USB to RJ45 adaptor*
  - *I have seen some javascript scraping on the admin interface of the router and I would like to avoid that if possible*

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, it is router-dependent. This TPLink probably doesn't support it at all

Comment: as far as I know, front-end scraping is your best bet, since this router has a proprietary software and not supporting sms export

Comment: @user12127811 [Here](https://github.com/fabiux/tplink_sms) is a python codes to send an sms, you just need to modify several parameters to scrape instead of send a message

Comment: @HastaDhana Thanks. However I am trying to use standard modem commands instead of web scraping..

there are plenty of examples of how to send sms using USB and openWrt such as on [link](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/advanced/howto.send.sms). I want to understand if this can be accomplished over RJ45 or if i need a RJ45 to USB adaptor.